# where can I define general functions in java project using android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

there are some functions that I use in most activities in the project, I want to have them defined somewhere and just call for them when needed.

I tried to store them in a Class its possible but not efficient, is there a file that i can store all these function definitions in?

Comment: *If* you really want to do that you need to create one central class and either make it a singleton or make the helper methods in it static.

Comment: You can declare them as static methods in a general class.

Comment: just create a Utility class and put all methods in it . You can also use `SingletonPattern` for it (In case) . Take reference from classes  of package `java.util`.

Comment: you could make a superclass that you could extend with every activity

Comment: One option is to create your own library and then import it into your project. This will only work if each of your methods are standalone however.

Comment: It would be helpful if you elaborated on why you state it is "not efficient" - possibly due to many dependencies (i.e. lots of parameters?) which may mean more decomposition.

Comment: @Andy "not efficient" is for the need to create an object of the class in order to call a function, but making it static (as mentioned in other comments) would raise the "efficiency".